# Java iterate over nested maps of list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map currently which is `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`

I want to do an operation on each item in each nested list.

I can do it with lots of nested for-loops:

(EDIT - Updating parameters of performOperation function)

```
final Set<ResultType> resultSet = new HashSet<>();
for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<String>>> topKeyEntry : inputNestedMap.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> innerKeyEntry : topKeyEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        for (String listItem : innerKeyEntry.getValue()) {
            resultSet.add(performOperation(listItem, topKeyEntry.getKey(), innerKeyEntry.getKey()));
        }
    }
}
```

***How do I do it with streams?***

I tried it with nesting `stream` and apply `map()` and eventually calling the operation in the innermost map, but that results in an error saying there is a return missing.

I tried to flatten the entry list with `flatMap()` but could not get through.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Matze._ I am trying to perform `performOperation ` on each item in the nested lusts and add it to a result set. that currently thats what I am doing with nest for's, but want to do with streams to be cleaner

Comment: I am not sure of a safe way, doing that for that many nested things, i prefer to keep it as simple as I can, so i don't come to an situation like this. Is there a way to simplify this all like unnesting some things?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot change the structure of the input map here

Comment: Why do you not want to use what you have?  I don't get the recent drive to want to convert all logic to streams and get it all packed onto one line.  I find the code you have to be very readable.  I expect that a streams equivalent would be less so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, I have posted the following.  It is essentially what you already have but in less cluttered form using the `forEach` method.

```
inputNestedMap.forEach((outerKey, innerMap) -> innerMap
        .forEach((innerKey, innerList) -> innerList.forEach(
                listItem -> resultSet.add(performOperation(
                            listItem, outerKey, innerKey)))));
```

And here is the modifed stream approach based on your changes.  I would stick with the nested for loop solution.

```
Set<ResultType> resultSet= inputNestedMap.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(outerEntrySet-> outerEntrySet.getValue()
            .entrySet().stream() // flatten outer entrySet
            .flatMap(innerEntrySet -> innerEntrySet
                    .getValue().stream(). // flatten inner entrySet
                     map(lstVal->performOperation(lstVal, // perform the operation
                            outerEntrySet.getKey(), 
                            innerEntrySet.getKey())))).
                    collect(Collectors.toSet());  // return as as set
```

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, this doesn't answer the question :(

Comment: You should know that it is acceptable to provide alternative, more efficient approaches if they are actually better.  This is done extremely often on this site and a vast majority of the time, well received.  Your down vote is completely unwarranted.

Comment: Quite the contrary.  I've removed the downvote after it had the desired effect. I consider your answer to be twice as good now, as it allows the OP and others that come later to both get what they were looking for and to benefit by your suggestion as to an alternative. - I would agree with you if it were clear that your alternative was universally better, but that isn't my opinion, and downvotes specifically exist to let me voice my opinion.

Comment: @Steve.  For your enlightenment.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386260/what-purpose-must-an-answer-serve

Comment: @WJS my bad :( I updated the parameters of `performOperation` function. It takes keys of two parent maps as well

Comment: @WJS - you misunderstood my objection I think.  My statement "this doesn't answer the question" didn't mean that I considered your answer to be wrong just because it didn't provide an answer that involved streams.  Rather, I found it to be wrong because it didn't explain WHY it is better to not use a streams approach.  All your initial answer did was improve upon the non-streams approach already provided.  Your answer still does not address the question of when to use a streams approach (or not).  Its only applicability is that its part 2 now provides an answer that addresses the question.

Comment: @nishant I updated my answer based on your correction.